# Calling VS Code from subprocess is non blocking unlike other editors

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, subprocess

I have been working on an application that spawns an editor from a script that helps edit a file in real time and save it (while the script is in progress).

It works perfectly when I use *Nano*, *Vim* or *Gedit*. However when I give it the argument to use *VS Code* then it fails. It opens the file in VS Code, then proceeds to the next line in the script, whereas for others its **blocking**, *which is what I want.*
Sample Code:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(['code', 'code.txt'])
subprocess.run(['nano', 'nano.text'])
subprocess.run(['vi', 'vim.txt'])
subprocess.run(['gedit', 'gedit.txt'])
```

**Behaviour**
When running this script in terminal, firstly the VS Code tab opens, however the terminal opens *nano*. Then you write and save something in *nano* and as soon as you close it, *vim* opens and similarly *gedit*. When you finally close *gedit*, you get a new prompt.
However, **if you change the code to open VS Code in the end**, then the terminal with show a **new prompt**, *without* even saving and closing your file opened in VS Code.

What is the reason behind behavior?

Comment: That's not a python problem. That's just how VS code works, code nohups itself from the process that launched it. Try running gedit or vim from the terminal and try killing the terminal, vim would die too. Gedit(Gnome) and Kate(KDE) block and do not nohup.

Comment: Interestingly enough gvim is not bound to the process that launched it

Comment: @Srini I did not know that. Thanks. If you want you can answer this question, maybe provide a link or a bit of explanation. I will accept it. Or should I delete this question?

Comment: I haven't really answered your question. So you should probably wait for someone who has a better answer :)